# How to increment a value to a new table when a given column string matches exactly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, aggregate-functions

mySQL can be easy, but can also be complicated especially when it's the first time trying to attempt to logically understand how to carry out a task and make the table visible as exact.

A question from my homework states:
How many times did each company interview?  Print out the companies with the most interviews first, then sort by company name in A-Z order.

```
+------------------------------+------------+
| companyname                  | Interviews |
+------------------------------+------------+
| Ajax Software, Inc.          |          2 |
| Cameron Industries           |          2 |
| Flordia Software Designs     |          2 |
| Manhattan-Made Software      |          2 |
| Mountainside Magic Software  |          2 |
| Acme Information Source      |          1 |
| ApplDesign                   |          1 |
<<<<<<< cut out some output >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
| Vegas Programming and Design |          1 |
| Virginia Software Industries |          1 |
+------------------------------+------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I got the first column perfectly by coding this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT companyname,
FROM interview
ORDER BY companyname ASC;
```

But the interviews, I'm trying to get the code for, if in companyname how ever many companies has the same exact strings to increment to the interview side. How does this work?

FULL OUTPUT:

```
+------------------------------+
| companyname                  |
+------------------------------+
| Acme Information Source      |
| Ajax Software, Inc.          |
| Ajax Software, Inc.          |
| ApplDesign                   |
| Bay Software Inc.            |
| Braddock Information Assoc.  |
| Buffalo Software Assoc.      |
| Cameron Industries           |
| Cameron Industries           |
| CCC Software                 |
| Davis-Klein Software         |
| DC Security Applications     |
| Flordia Software Designs     |
| Flordia Software Designs     |
| Focused Applications, Inc.   |
| Georgia Software Design      |
| Jersey Computer Services     |
| Long Island Apps, Inc.       |
| Manhattan-Made Software      |
| Manhattan-Made Software      |
| Mountainside Magic Software  |
| Mountainside Magic Software  |
| Nantucket Applications, Inc. |
| PennState Programming, Inc.  |
| Rochester Software Design    |
| Sandy Hook Software          |
| Vegas Programming and Design |
| Virginia Software Industries |
+------------------------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what is you logic behind cut out some output? you want to cut out company start with letter V.

Comment: cut out some output just contains a lot more of the companies' names, thats all.

Comment: Sorry, if i wasn't clear enough, but it is the Interviews column I want. Simply, if companyname column has a found a match every time, it increments interviews +1 on that specifc companyname.

Comment: that meaans you want sum of Interviews of the specific company and sort by highest interview.

Comment: does my query meet what you want. or i wasn't clear enought

Comment: doesn't work. :(, it still shows a value of zero and only shows the first companyname, thats it.

Comment: so what you want...... explain me clearly

Comment: How many times did each company interview?  Print out the companies with the most interviews first, then sort by company name in A-Z order.

what i want is for mysql to recognize how many interviews were conducted by the same company names as there are some company names repeated in the companyname column, then creates AS "Interviews" to put in the number of interviews found.

Comment: Now check the deomo i have modifed in the answer.

Comment: Trying to do this  wiithoug seeing some sample data could take a while... post up a sqlfiddle - with just enough INSERTs to be properly representative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check if it works

```
SELECT companyname ,count(companyname) as interviews
from interview GROUP BY companyname order by interviews desc, companyname asc
```

[**Check To see YOu demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/827de/2)

Comment: Just to be correct, the interview table contains companyname and then creates the "Interviews" column that track companies # of interviews. The interviews table values are still zero though. Should I provide more tables related to this?

    SELECT companyname, SUM("Interviews") AS "Interviews"
    FROM interview GROUP BY companyname 
    ORDER BY "Interviews" DESC, companyname ASC;

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight it seems like you donot have interview column. you have to count company to find the interview. am i Right?

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight now check the latest query. I hope this will meet your requirement.